# Calculating miniscule numbers for chi-squared distribution -- numerical precision

Tags: r, statistics, precision, chi-squared

I am using the `pchisq` function in R to calculate the cumulative distribution function for the chi-squared distribution. I would like to calculate very small values, such that `1-pchisq(...)` can have a value smaller than 2.2e-16 (which is the numerical precision limit for R's numeric format). Right now, these very small values simply become 0.

Things I've tried:

- Setting the digits display option to 22 (max)
- Using the `Rmpfr` package for increased precision, but that number format doesn't work with the `pchisq` function
- Breaking the CDF function into its component gamma functions, but that results in similar precision limits. Any ideas on how I can calculate what I want?

Background: I'm using [Fisher's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method) to combine a bunch of p-values. Yes, I know these p-values are minuscule, but it is actually useful for what I'm analyzing.

Comment: this is probably a wrong place to ask about stats.

Comment: could you compute log(1-pchisq) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things.

- 2.2e-16 is *not* the lower precision limit of values in R; it's just the way that R prints very small p-values by default, using `format.pval`:

```
format.pval(1e-20)
## [1] "< 2.22e-16"
```

- values smaller than approximately 1e-320 *do* round down to zero:

```
1e-330
## [1] 0
```

@SeverinPappadeux's suggestion is exactly right:

```
pchisq(121231,1,lower.tail=FALSE,log.p=TRUE)
## [1] -60621.58
```

This is equivalent to 10^(-26327):

```
-60621.58/log(10)
## -26327.62
```

Check for a less extreme value:

```
log10(pchisq(100,1,lower.tail=FALSE) )
## [1] -22.81702
pchisq(100,1,lower.tail=FALSE,log.p=TRUE)/log(10)
## [1] -22.81702
```

Furthermore, `log(p)` is exactly what you need to use for Fisher's method.